# Coda Slider Problem - Works in Firefox, Not Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome

I am building a page that is employing several different javascript elements and I seem to have run into a problem I haven't before (not surprising as I am new to javascript).

I have implemented the tutorial for the JQuery Coda Slider located here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/.

It seems that the sliding effect works when I run it it Firefox but not Chrome or Safari. Wondering if this is a common issue and if I am missing something obvious.

To help, I am attaching the  code of the page I am working on as it may help you understand the scripts I am using.

```
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" media="screen" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.73.js"></script>
    <script src= "js/banner.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

EDIT: slider.js

```
// when the DOM is ready...
$(document).ready(function () {

var $panels = $('#slider .scrollContainer > div');
var $container = $('#slider .scrollContainer');

// if false, we'll float all the panels left and fix the width 
// of the container
var horizontal = true;

// float the panels left if we're going horizontal
if (horizontal) {
  $panels.css({
    'float' : 'left',
    'position' : 'relative' // IE fix to ensure overflow is hidden
  });

  // calculate a new width for the container (so it holds all panels)
  $container.css('width', $panels[0].offsetWidth * $panels.length);
}

// collect the scroll object, at the same time apply the hidden overflow
// to remove the default scrollbars that will appear
var $scroll = $('#slider .scroll').css('overflow', 'hidden');

// apply our left + right buttons
$scroll
  .before('<img class="scrollButtons left" src="images/scroll_left.png" />')
  .after('<img class="scrollButtons right" src="images/scroll_right.png" />');

// handle nav selection
function selectNav() {
  $(this)
    .parents('ul:first')
      .find('a')
        .removeClass('selected')
      .end()
    .end()
    .addClass('selected');
}

$('#slider .navigation').find('a').click(selectNav);

// go find the navigation link that has this target and select the nav
function trigger(data) {
  var el = $('#slider .navigation').find('a[href$="' + data.id + '"]').get(0);
  selectNav.call(el);
}

if (window.location.hash) {
  trigger({ id : window.location.hash.substr(1) });
} else {
  $('ul.navigation a:first').click();
}

// offset is used to move to *exactly* the right place, since I'm using
// padding on my example, I need to subtract the amount of padding to
// the offset.  Try removing this to get a good idea of the effect
var offset = parseInt((horizontal ? 
  $container.css('paddingTop') : 
  $container.css('paddingLeft')) 
  || 0) * -1;


var scrollOptions = {
  target: $scroll, // the element that has the overflow

  // can be a selector which will be relative to the target
  items: $panels,

  navigation: '.navigation a',

  // selectors are NOT relative to document, i.e. make sure they're unique
  prev: 'img.left', 
  next: 'img.right',

  // allow the scroll effect to run both directions
  axis: 'xy',

  onAfter: trigger, // our final callback

  offset: offset,

  // duration of the sliding effect
  duration: 500,

  // easing - can be used with the easing plugin: 
  // http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
  easing: 'swing'
};

// apply serialScroll to the slider - we chose this plugin because it 
// supports// the indexed next and previous scroll along with hooking 
// in to our navigation.
$('#slider').serialScroll(scrollOptions);

// now apply localScroll to hook any other arbitrary links to trigger 
// the effect
$.localScroll(scrollOptions);

// finally, if the URL has a hash, move the slider in to position, 
// setting the duration to 1 because I don't want it to scroll in the
// very first page load.  We don't always need this, but it ensures
// the positioning is absolutely spot on when the pages loads.
scrollOptions.duration = 1;
$.localScroll.hash(scrollOptions);

});
```

Comment: @bgadoci Whats more important is the actual jQuery code that implements the slider and attaches the events, etc. Can you post that? Possibly through a service like http://pastie.org if its really long.

Comment: @doug I just added the slider.js code. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Yup! thanks... this will help in finding a fix

Comment: OK, just read through the code and there is nothing glaring. At this point it could be your HTML, your CSS, etc. Can you put together simple HTML test page and upload it somewhere for us/me to troubleshoot? Sorry I can't help more with just what is posted.

Comment: No problem, I really appreciate the help. Give me a little bit to get it up.

Comment: My hosting company is "experience performance issues". Please don't for get about me.

Comment: @bgadoci Don't worry i won't If it gets to late (I am EST) I'll look at it tomorrow for you. I don't mind if you hit me up on twitter when you finally post: @dougneiner

Comment: Fixed. Just changed the .min.js versions of scrollTo, etc. to the full versions. Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why didn't you just copy "http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html" Its a reduction of what you need. Remember you need these:

```
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jquery.scrollTo-1.3.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jquery.localscroll-1.2.5.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="jquery.serialScroll-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="coda-slider.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And the HTML should be similar (view source to find out). It works great in Chrome.

Comment: Isn't that what I have. I just copied the most recent dowloads of JQuery and the Scroll series file name to the head link. What am I missing?

Comment: Try copying and pasting http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html it should work on all browsers. Without knowing your HTML or your reduced sample, it is unknown what the problem you are facing. Must be something small syntax error. Try validating it.

Answer (score 1):

after hours searching and debugging I found out the solution. jQuery interfears with joomla included mootools. Remove it with the following code in your index.php header:

```
<?php 
        //remove mootools.js and caption.js
        $headerstuff=$this->getHeadData();
        reset($headerstuff['scripts']);
        foreach($headerstuff['scripts'] as $key=>$value){
          unset($headerstuff['scripts'][$key]);
        }       
        $this->setHeadData($headerstuff);
        ?>
```